# Codeigniter count_all_results then get return error number 1066

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I want to count all result by using `$this->db->count_all_results()` in my query then get the query result *(`$this->db->get`)* without reset any field value. i have followed the user guide on [Limiting or Counting Results](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results) it's say

However, this method also resets any field values that you may have passed to select(). If you need to keep them, you can pass FALSE as the second parameter:

i have passed FALSE parameter to the function but i get Database Error:

> Error Number: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'my_table'

this is the  code i have tried

```
$this->db->select('title', 'content', 'date');
$this->db->like('title', 'Post');
$this->db->order_by('title', 'DESC');

$records = $this->db->count_all_results('my_table', FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('my_table', 20);
```

***Thanks***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Make an alias of `my_table` in `count_all_results` like the below:*

```
$this->db->select('p.title, p.content, p.date');
$this->db->like('p.title', 'title');
$this->db->order_by('p.date', 'DESC');

$data['count'] = $this->db->count_all_results('my_table p', FALSE);
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('my_table')->result();
print_r($data);
```

for more : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Comment: can you give me a good reference about alias. is it a sql statement or codeigniter term ? and why i must to use alias

Comment: did it work for u? its mysql term, i have tested it and used it , just try then let me know its working for you or not,

Comment: I'm sure its working, but its not easy to implement because my `select` and `like` statement is an array that also used in other function. should i modify the string in array before passed to the `select` ? or you have other suggestion ?

Comment: in like clause u can pass an array as docs says, but in select clause you have to pass comma separated string as in my answer, if ur select is an array u can use implode method to convert it in comma separated values, and  use `array_map` to add  table alias to every element of an array

Comment: by the way if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it as green and do upvote also

Answer (score 1):

Why not just count the rows from the query resultset like so:

```
$this->db->select('title', 'content', 'date');
$this->db->like('title', 'Post');
$this->db->order_by('title', 'DESC');

$query = $this->db->get('my_table');

$records = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: oh yes i'm forget. because i want to limit query result to 20. $query = $this->db->get('my_table', 20);

Comment: so what the different between limit and $records, is not the same value (20) ? i want to know how many record exactly but want to limit the query result.

Comment: limit only returns a maximum of this number of results. `$records` in my example will return the actual number of rows that were returned - i.e - <= 20

Comment: yes i know about it. but i want to know how many records before limited based  on sql statement and then get query result with desired limit.

Comment: You don't need to!!! Take the limit part off my query - this will then return all results. You can then use the `$records` variable to display the number of rows in your view if you need to. In short, not setting a limit will return all rows that match your query - you don't need to know the limit first!

Comment: of course i can limit how many record that will be displayed with simple php script. but i just want to know ho to use `count_all_results`

Comment: Dude, you don't need to use it if it is causing you problems. The answer which I posted performs the same outcome and does not cause you any issues!!!

Comment: nice idea dude.

Comment: All this effort (correct answer) and you decide to award to someone else with no upvote for me? What the hell?